# Python How to Handle Data Unstructured From Text File

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, pyspark

i have file format like this.

```
# Jon Doe
# 27212000-C
# Calorina, 06/03 1993
# South Calorina Jaka Km 1
# Num 009.006
# Calorina. 11710, Tp.108437347343
# joe.st'a gmail.com
# 20-09-2016 Akn

# 36412506/E.15262
# Jakarta, 13/10/1994
# II, Let.jend, Soeprapto Gang Siaga
# V RT 005/03
# Jakarta, 10640. Tp.
# 22-09-2016/T Info

# Jenny Doe
# 5641141 2/E.15263
# Zimbabwe, 05/06/1993
# Mujair Street Iv No.185 
# Mujair, 15116. Tp.04545454
# jenny@gmail.com
# 22-09-2016/T Info

# Igor Kart
# 36412777/E,15264
# Kongo, 30/10/1994
# Kp. Pintu Air Kel. Pabuaran Kec.Boj
# onggede Kab.Bogor RT 04/09
# Bogor, 16320. Tp,107262626
# igor.@gmail.com
# 22-09-2016T Info
```

how get best structure data from the output?
i want get a result csv like this. Good_format.csv

```
Name        Code                    Bday                    Address                                                                        Phone         Email                  Info
Jon Doe     27212000-C              Calorina, 06/03 1993    South Calorina Jaka Km 1Num 009.006 Calorina. 11710                            108437347343  joe.st'a gmail.com     20-09-2016 Akn
Jenny Doe   5641141 2/E.15263       Zimbabwe, 05/06/1993    Mujair Street Iv No.185 Mujair, 15116.                                         04545454      jenny@gmail.com        22-09-2016/T Info
Igor Kart   36412777/E,15264        Kongo, 30/10/1993       Kp. Pintu Air Kel. Pabuaran Kec.Bojonggede Kab.Bogor RT 04/09Bogor, 16320.     107262626     igor.@gmail.com        22-09-2016T Info
```

and record bad format to log.txt.
i need bad format for me to fix it again.

```
# 36412506/E.15262
# Jakarta, 13/10/1994
# II, Let.jend, 
# V RT 005/03
# Jakarta, 10640. Tp.
# 22-09-2016/T Info
```

Comment: the only thing i can think of is use regex rule to get the pattern match to each column

Comment: thank you my friend. can you give me sample code?

Comment: @Hendra We're not here to help you do your work. Please at least give an effort to try.

Comment: hi @mck, I'm sorry to bother you with my limited abilities. sorry didn't attach my experiment. Thank you for the advice, my friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate

filepath     = "SO.txt"

colList = ['Name', 'Code', 'Bday', 'Address', 'Phone', 'Email', 'Info']
df_full = pd.DataFrame(columns = colList)
                       
with open(filepath) as fp:
    contents = fp.read()
    #print(contents)
    groups = [[line.split("#")[1].strip() for line in group.split("\n") if line != ""] for group in contents.split("\n\n")]
    #print(groups)
    for groupInd, group in enumerate(groups):
        df_temp  = pd.DataFrame(columns = colList, index = [groupInd])
        #If first line of each group contains at least a number, then the above code returns True 
        if not(any(chr.isdigit() for chr in group[0])):
            df_temp.Name    = group[0]
            df_temp.Code    = group[1]
            df_temp.Bday    = group[2]
            
            #####
            #Concatenate a list of address and phone lines into one string
            temp = ' '.join(group[3:-2]).split('Tp')
            df_temp.Address = temp[0]
            #Extract digit string means remove commas, dots, ...        
            df_temp.Phone   = ''.join(filter(lambda i: i.isdigit(), temp[1]))
            #####

            df_temp.Email   = group[-2]
            df_temp.Info    = group[-1]
        
            df_full = pd.concat([df_full, df_temp], axis=0)
            
    print(tabulate(df_full, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))
```

**The output:**

```
+----+-----------+-------------------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+--------------------+-------------------+
|    | Name      | Code              | Bday                 | Address                                                                      |        Phone | Email              | Info              |
|----+-----------+-------------------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+--------------------+-------------------|
|  0 | Jon Doe   | 27212000-C        | Calorina, 06/03 1993 | South Calorina Jaka Km 1 Num 009.006 Calorina. 11710,                        | 108437347343 | joe.st'a gmail.com | 20-09-2016 Akn    |
|  2 | Jenny Doe | 5641141 2/E.15263 | Zimbabwe, 05/06/1993 | Mujair Street Iv No.185 Mujair, 15116.                                       |     04545454 | jenny@gmail.com    | 22-09-2016/T Info |
|  3 | Igor Kart | 36412777/E,15264  | Kongo, 30/10/1994    | Kp. Pintu Air Kel. Pabuaran Kec.Boj onggede Kab.Bogor RT 04/09 Bogor, 16320. |    107262626 | igor.@gmail.com    | 22-09-2016T Info  |
+----+-----------+-------------------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+--------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: No problems at all!